# How do you create an Airport service remotely?

Tags: networking, macos, command-line

I have been scouring the net for over an hour and can't find an anwser as to how to create an Airport network service using the command line. If I use

```
networksetup listallnetworkservices
Bluetooth DUN
Ethernet
local
```

the airport service is obviously not there. If I use ARD and manually create the Airport service I see

```
networksetup listallnetworkservices
Bluetooth DUN
Ethernet
local
Airport
```

So the question is how to create it from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `networksetup -createnetworkservice Foobar en1`

> Usage: `networksetup -createnetworkservice <newnetworkservicename> <hardwareport>`
>   Create a service named  on port . The new service will be enabled by default.

(you might want to replace *Foobar* with *AirPort* though)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Some Macs don't use `en1` for the wifi device. Check Apple documentation for your device.

Comment: Actually this worked quite well:
    networksetup -createnetworkservice Airport Airport